# Enabling geolocation in web browser

Tags: browser, geolocation

I'm partially unable to get geolocation within a web browser.  When the phone-wide "use wifi for location" box is unchecked, going to a new website the requires geolocation fails.  For example, maps.google.com gives the the error "Your location could not be determined."  When I check the box, I get the permission request dialog, and after that, I can get geolocation regardless of the "wifi geolocation" option.

- The GPS works fine, and the Maps app works fine.
- I have enabled geolocation in the browser settings.
- I have tried this with the stock browser, Dolphin, and a custom app with a WebView (with the appropriate permissions set up).  I get the same result on all three.  I also got the same result using the Android emulator on my PC.
- The phone does not have a cellular plan.
- Android 2.2 on a Motorola Droid

At this point, I have a workaround, but does anyone have clues about what's going on?

Comment: Have you installed `Permission Fix` app?

Comment: No, I have not.